# sql query to remove prefix from field

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given the following

```
Products_Joined.ProductName AS [stripHTML-TITLE],
```

How would I remove the first 5 characters  when the field contain any of the following. Basically I want to strip out the characters between < and > and including <> as well. The returned field's length can vary.

```
<!01>AMSSSS
<!02>SSS
<!03>CMSS
<!04>DMSS
<!05>EMSDDDDD etc...
```

This gives me just the first characters after the > but I don't know how to get all characters after >

```
SUBSTRING(Products_Joined.ProductName, 6,1) AS [stripHTML-TITLE],
```

Was going to use Replace function for all the possible prefixes but that can get rather messy.

Comment: just leave the last parmaeter blank for the remainder of the string.

Comment: that doesn't work, tried that, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SUBSTRING(Products_Joined.ProductName, 6,LEN(Products_Joined.ProductName))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use STUFF.

```
select stuff('<!01>AMSSSS', 1, 5, '')
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx